# How to get user's project list in JSON at Github

Tags: json, api, github

I'm trying to find the github api to get user's project list in JSON, have tried to read the documentation but I didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [GitHub API calls are using JSON](https://developer.github.com/v3/#schema), you could use the [List user projects call](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/#list-user-projects)

```
GET /users/:username/projects
```

That would list public projects, in a JSON array.

For instance:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" -k https://api.github.com/users/<YourAccount>/projects
```

Replace `/projects` by `/repos` for listing repositories instead.